# How To Cut a Portion Of Audio With the Help of vlcj

Tags: java, vlcj

How is it possible to cut a portion of a audo with the help of vlcj ? This is what I have been doing so far but it cuts the music from the given start time till the  End of the Audio not till the given stop time.

> mediaPlayer.playMedia(url,":start-time=100",
>   ":stoptime=210",":sout=/home/raman/Music/6.mp3");

Answer (score 0):

":stoptime=210" should be ":stop-time=210".